# PhpStorm hides only node_modules for every project

Tags: phpstorm, node-modules

I tried updating, I tried removing `.idea` folders from the projects. I even deleted my whole settings folder from users/User in Windows. Last one helped, but I had to import my old settings, there is just far too much changed for me to redo everything, problem reappeared.

While indexing, PhpStorm shows the `node_modules` folder. Right after it finishes, the folder disappears. I have no scopes set up, I have not excluded the folder.

I followed this issue [PhpStorm hides directories in Project window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445099/phpstorm-hides-directories-in-project-window) and it didn't help.

If I setup `node_modules` as a source folder from the Directories settings, and then choose "Project Files" from the Project View, then and only then I can see it in the sidenav... This is driving me nuts...

Comment: mine was ok until today... then i installed vue (npm install vue) and it's gone from project explorer... if i select "project files", it's there, but not in project view anymore.

Comment: Yep that's the issue. But its not with Vue only. I have few other projects that don't have Vue and still have the same issue.

Its really frustrating. While its indexing, the folder is there and visible. The moment indexing finishes, the node_modules folder is gone.

Comment: exactly that... indexing it's visible, then gone.

Comment: If you want, you can send me an archive of your settings folder and I will compare with mine and then to my colleague's, he doesnt have this problem. But I compared his to mine and got nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I disabled "Vue for Idea" plugin and node_modules reappeared. I feel so stupid right now....
Thanks to [Alexandre Martini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621287/alexandre-martini) in the comments. He gave me a hunch.

Comment: yeah, that was it... it's a bug that the plugin developer says he introduced on purpose, but doesn't explain why. go figure...

Comment: Thanks for that. Never expected a plugin to cause this.

Comment: Author stated that this is intentional...  You can check his github repo.

Comment: Link to this issue: https://github.com/henjue/vue-for-idea/issues/46
Also you may try https://github.com/postalservice14/vuejs-plugin instead

Comment: @DobromirHristov I had the same issue, but without using Vue plugin, then I figure out that node_modules was ignored in Settings > File Type, [details how I fix it](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203372590/comments/115000133390). Now it's me who feel so stupid after many hours trying to figure that out.

Answer (score -3):

This shit drove me crazy to - Go to File > Settings > Frameworks > Javascripts > Libraries and make sure you have a library setup pointing to your project's node_modules folder and the visibility is enabled. This link helped me.

[[How to configure WebStorm / PhpStorm project so that JS code intelligence works well for Node.js projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705538/how-to-configure-webstorm-phpstorm-project-so-that-js-code-intelligence-works][1])